# Does Deconstructing an SDL_Texture Call SDL_DestroyTexture?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm managing a `vector` of `unique_ptr`s to some `SDL_Texture`s. When I quit the program, do I have to call `SDL_DestroyTexture` on all remaining textures in the `vector`, or does the destructor called by the deconstruction of `unique_ptr` take care of that?

Example code:

```
void foo(SDL_Renderer* renderer, const char* filePath) {
    // assume SDL is already initialized
    auto ptr = std::unique_ptr<SDL_Texture>(IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, filePath));
}
```

Is the `SDL_Texture` that was created properly destroyed after this function finishes?

I looked around in the source code a little bit, but wasn't able to find my way through to the actual definition of `SDL_Texture`.

Comment: did you try to put a breakpoint in `SDL_DestroyTexture`? You can find it in SDL sources by simple text search